# How to properly handle WCF faults with Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

No matter how hard I try I cannot seem to be able to handle WCF faults in Silverlight.
In fact the error seems to never leave the server !

E.g. when I debug it, it stops on the line where I throw the FaultException saying it was not handled:

```
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class StoreService : IStoreContract
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<string> GetStoreDesignNames()
    {
        try
        {
            StoreDataContext swdc = new StoreDataContext();
            var query = from storeDesign in swdc.StoreDesignDBs select storeDesign.Name;
            return query.ToList();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlExcept)
        {
            throw new FaultException<SqlFault>(new SqlFault() { Message = sqlExcept.Message });
        }
    }
}
```

The class that implements this method derives from a contract interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Store")]
public interface IStoreContract
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtain the list of store design names.
    /// </summary>
    [OperationContract,
     FaultContract(typeof(SqlFault))]
    List<String> GetStoreDesignNames();
}
```

And the SqlFault class is defined like this:

```
public class SqlFault
{
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

On the client side I handle the error as follow:

```
        // swc is the client
        swc.GetStoreDesignNamesCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.GetStoreDesignNamesCompletedEventArgs>((obj, evt) =>
        {
            if (evt.Error == null)
            {
                // In case of success
                MessageBox.Show(evt.Result.First());
            }
            else if (evt.Error is FaultException<ServiceReference.SqlFault>)
            {
                FaultException<ServiceReference.SqlFault> fault = evt.Error as FaultException<ServiceReference.SqlFault>;
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    ErrorWindow ew = new ErrorWindow(fault.Detail.Message, "No details");
                    ew.Show();
                });
            }
        });
        swc.GetStoreDesignNamesAsync();
```

I have tried to put the [SilverlightFaultBehavior] attribute on the interface, to no avail. Even if I do without the interface I still have this error.

I have also tried to use a behavior extension in the web.config as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but I get a warning saying the extension is not valid.

How does one go about properly handling WCF fault in Siverlight ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After battling with this for hours I finally hacked something together that works.
This is really a horrible hack and I would have much preferred to use BehaviorExtension for this task. The trick is to set manually the HTTP status code in the body of the WCF method like so:

```
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<string> GetStoreDesignNames()
    {
        try
        {
            StoreDataContext swdc = new StoreDataContext();
            var query = from storeDesign in swdc.StoreDesignDBs select storeDesign.Name;
            return query.ToList();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlExcept)
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext ctx = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current;
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            throw new FaultException<SqlFault>(new SqlFault() { Message = sqlExcept.Message });
        }
    }
```

The error message then correctly displays on the client side.
If anybody has a better solution than this I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used WCF (been using WCF RIA Services) but I did come across this article a while ago.

[Getting something better than “Server not found.” from WCF in Silverlight](http://mattduffield.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/getting-something-better-than-server-not-found-from-wcf-in-silverlight/)